# scraping multiple page table with unchanging URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the data from all the pages on this URL: https://ocrportal.hhs.gov/ocr/breach/breach_report.jsf
The URL does not change when you click on the next page. I googled how to do it, but didn't find a solution/didn't understand it. I don't understand how to make it loop through all the pages and get the data.

My current code (it only grips the data from the first page):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ocrportal.hhs.gov/ocr/breach/breach_report.jsf'

def getdata(your_url):
    page = requests.get(your_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    table1 = soup.find('div', id='ocrForm:reportResultTable')
    headers = []
    
    for i in table1.find_all('th'):
        title = i.text
        headers.append(title)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
    
    for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        row_data = j.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in row_data]
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row
    df = df.drop(['Expand All'], axis=1)    
    return df

df = getdata(your_url = url)
df
```